# Is it possible to cause segmentation fault by changing library file when using dynamic library(dlopen)?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I was made `test_program` that using dynamic library and working as linux daemon.

The `test_program` contains a code initialize process.

`dlopen(libtest.so);`

**Normally, terminates `test_program` with sigkill does not cause segmentation fault**(I double checked!!)

**But when terminated with overwritten `libtest.so` file**(eg. `cp libtest.so /lib64/libtest.so`) **cause segmentation fault**.

**the library file accidentally overwritted and the file is actually same `libtest.so`**(I was diffed).

I would be very appreciated to know why segmentation fault happen when library file overwritten.

Thanks for reading and I Attached Backtrace of generated corefile and dmesg so please let me know if you need more information.

backtrace(parted):

```
#0  0x00007fd2c7668118 in ?? () from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
#1  0x00007fd2c7669019 in _Unwind_Backtrace () from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
#2  0x00007fd2c73a2186 in backtrace () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000000050fda8 in print_trace (sig=11, siginfo=0x7fff87da5770, context=<optimized out>) at sighandler.c:239
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  0x0000000000018219 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fd2c9c47a1a in _dl_fini () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#7  0x00007fd2c72d0e69 in __run_exit_handlers () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#8  0x00007fd2c72d0eb5 in exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#9  0x000000000050d655 in end_signal (signo=<optimized out>) at 
#10 <signal handler called>test_program.c:103
```

dmesg:

```
test_program[11817]: segfault at 18219 ip 00007fd2c7668118 sp 00007fff87da4f40 error 4 in libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1[7fd2c7659000+15000]
```

Comment: `man dlclose` "*Errors from these functions can be diagnosed using dlerror(3)*" -- Specific to your issue, what occurs when `dlcose` is called (perhaps implicitly) and the file is no longer there?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried to put dlerror but it segfault when dlclose called,And the file's location is not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally, terminates test_program with sigkill does not cause
>   segmentation fault(I double checked!!)

SIGKILL cannot be caught nor ignored and prevents any further userspace code execution. This implies it *never* causes a segmentation fault. Perhaps you meant SIGTERM.

> But when terminated with overwritten libtest.so file(eg. cp libtest.so
>   /lib64/libtest.so) cause segmentation fault.

The very backtrace you paste shows how the process tried to clean up after itself, therefore it could not have received SIGKILL.

> the library file accidentally overwritted and the file is actually
>   same libtest.so(I was diffed).

The file may be the same, but IS NOT the same in memory mapped to the process. cp doing truncate on the file and overwriting the content "restored" the original state.

Even if the modified state was to remain, the time window between truncate and finishing up writing presents a crash potential: either the area is not backed by the file (which gives SIGBUS), the to-be-executed code is not written yet and the area is just zeroed (instant SIGSEGV), or the instruction is partially written and looks bogus (SIGILL).

tl;dr don't do that

Comment: What usually happens when a file is replaced in place (truncated and rewritten) is that privately mapped writable data regions are cleared, also leading to crashes. This kind of failure does not involve a race condition, so it is much more common.